# React Native - getTranslateTransform() of Animated Value make error on Android virtual device

Tags: android, react-native, animation, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing draggable component with react-native.
And this component wokrs well on my IOS device.
However, when I test this component on virtual android device, it makes error like this:

**Error while updating property 'transform' of a view managed by: RCTView**

**null**

**Value for translateX cannot be cast from String to Double**

And below is my code

```
export default class DraggableTouchableOpacity extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.pan = new Animated.ValueXY();
    this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
        this.pan.setOffset({x: this.pan.x, y: this.pan.y});
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {
        this.pan.setValue({x: gestureState.dx, y: gestureState.dy});
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: (e) => {
        Animated.spring(this.pan, {
          toValue: {x: 0, y: 0},
          friction: 5
        }).start();
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Animated.View
          style = {{
            transform: this.pan.getTranslateTransform()
          }}
          {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity {...this.props} ref = {view => { this.myComponent = view; }}/>
        </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setOffset inside onPanResponderGrand causing the error

Change that function

```
onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
    this.pan.setOffset({x: this.pan.x, y: this.pan.y});
},
```

to

```
onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
   this.pan.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
},
```